# I have a TextArea in javafx but I need to get the coordinates or positions (x, y) to move a floating menu inside a TextArea

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I have a problem and I cannot find out how to solve it. I searched the internet and have not found any information that tells me how I can get the coordinates or the position (x, y) of the caret inside a `TextArea` with JavaFX.

Comment: So you want the (x, y) coordinates of the mouse inside the `TextArea` so that, for example, the top-left corner of the `TextArea` returns (0, 0)?

Comment: I need to obtain the position (x, y) of the cursor that has the TextArea so that according to the position in which the cursor is able to move a Pane that is inside the TextArea I do not know if the mouse positions inside the TextArea work for me

Comment: The cursor of text, the caretposition. I need the coordinates of the caretposition in javafx

Answer (score 2):

TextInputControl has a property caretPosition which denotes the position as char-index-in-text. The collaborator that translates the text coordinate into (x,y) coordinate is its skin: TextInputControlSkin provides a conversion method `getCharacterBounds(index)`.

So the way to keep track of the caret position in (x, y) coordinates is to

1. listen to the control's caret position in text coordinate
2. query its skin to translate a text coordinate into a 2D coordinate
3. use those to position a node

The simple example below shows a red rectangle around the caret.

```
public class TextCaretPosition extends Application  {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("TextArea Experiment 1");

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea("This is all\nmy text\nin here.");

        ObjectProperty<Rectangle> caretShape = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        textArea.caretPositionProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv ) -> {
            TextInputControlSkin<TextArea> skin = (TextInputControlSkin<TextArea>) textArea.getSkin();
            if (skin != null) {
                Rectangle2D bounds = skin.getCharacterBounds(nv.intValue());
                caretShape.set(new Rectangle(bounds.getMinX(), bounds.getMinY(), 
                        bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight()));
            }
        });
        caretShape.addListener((src, ov, r) -> {
            Skin<?> skin = textArea.getSkin();
            if (skin instanceof SkinBase) {
                if (ov != null) {
                    ((SkinBase<?>) skin).getChildren().remove(ov);
                } 
                if (r != null) {
                    r.setStroke(Color.RED);
                    r.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    r.setMouseTransparent(true);
                    ((SkinBase<?>) skin).getChildren().add(r);
                }
            }
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox(textArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 200, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```